# Android accelerometer frequency domain analysis FFT

Tags: android, fft, accelerometer, dft, spectrum

I want to create an android app for vibrations analysis using embedded accelerometer, would you suggest an easy solution/library to get a frequency spectrum out of the x,y,z accelerations?